# MongoDB Collection Level Permission Issues

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to set up a MongoDB user that only has access to certain collections across several databases.  The issue is that these databases are created dynamically at runtime.

I decided to employ collection level access in order to do this with the following permission on the user role:

```
"db" : "admin",
"privileges" : [ 
    {
        "resource " : {
            "cluster" : true
        },
        "actions" : [ 
            "listDatabases"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "resource" : {
            "db" : "",
            "collection" : "packages"
        },
        "actions" : [ 
            "find", 
            "insert", 
            "remove", 
            "update", 
            "listCollections"
        ]
    }]
```

What I want is for any user with this role to be able to read/write/remove in any database but only on the packages collection inside of that database, and be unable to read or write to any other collection.  When I launch mongod in --auth I do not see any databases besides admin.

I am certain this is just me being unable to figure out exactly what actions / resources / roles I am supposed to grant.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you mean but this could be a solution:

```
var role = "<role name>"; 
admin = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
if (admin.getRoles({ rolesInfo: role }).length == 0)
   admin.createRole({ role: role, privileges: [], roles: [] });
admin.grantRolesToUser(<the user>, [role]);
```

Then you would have to run this code every time when a new database is created.

```
db.getSiblingDB(<your dynamic database name>).getCollectionNames().forEach(function (item) {
   db.getSiblingDB("admin").grantPrivilegesToRole(role, [{
      resource: {
         db: <your dynamic database name>, collection: item }, 
         actions: ["find", "insert", "remove", "update"] }])
   })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding,


From what I understand according to this documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/

I should be able to set a role to look at any database by setting the resource value to db: "".

I then should be able to access a collection by setting the resource to collection: "MyCollection"

However, when I use the role above, I can only see the system collections in the Admin db.

Does this better explain my problem?  I would prefer not to do what you suggested when the above linked method seems cleaner.

Comment: No, the user can see collection `MyCollection` in `db: <xyz>` database - `admin` is the database where the role is defined. Yes, you can use `db: ""` - however if by chance somebody creates a collection called `MyCollection` then the user can see it. So, it might be a security flaw.

Comment: It would only be a security flaw if MyCollection ever had data that was never intended for the user to see, which shouldn't be an issue.  I don't really know if Mongo would suggest in their own documentation about security to do something that would be a security risk.


The problem I am experiencing is that using db: "" and collection:MyCollection doesn't give access to the DBs with MyCollection available.  I only have access to the System collections in Admin, which is not what I want.

Comment: I created the user in admin -- according to the documentation that is required to use this type of collection-level access.  It connects to the DB through the 27017 default port, though the user does not work properly when connecting directly through the mongo shell either.

I imagine there is some basic permission I am missing that I am just overlooking.  I tried to give the role permissions to a specific DB and a specific collection and that is not working either.  I also verified the user does have the proper role just to make sure I didn't make a big oversight there.

Comment: getRoles does not return any of my user-defined roles (I made sure to set rolesInfo to 1).  However, System.Roles does show the roles I have created.  I created the roles using db.createRole()

Comment: On which database did you run `db.getRoles`?

Comment: I recreated the role and it seems to be working and showing properly now.  I am not quite certain what happened but everything looks to be working how I expected it should be.  Thanks for bearing with me!

Answer (score 1):

TLDR for anyone having a similar issue:

It seems like there was an issue when initially creating the roles through Robo3T instead of through the mongo shell.  I created the same user through the shell and it works properly.